# Does Avenza MAPublisher update a shapefile if it has been edited in another application (e.g. ArcMap)?

Tags: shapefile, illustrator, avenza, mapublisher

I have imported a shapefile of trails into Adobe Illustrator using the MAPublisher plugin. Then I edited that shapefile in ArcMap.

Is there a way to re-link to that file so that the Illustrator layer reflects the changes made?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MAPublisher does not update based on changes made outside the document/program.  Any changes that you make to the shapefile outside of MAPublisher, will require you to re-import the file.

Kate B
Avenza Support